# HAProxy set authorization header from cookie

Tags: haproxy

I have a backend that I don't control that works using magic links. If I use the magic link, I don't have to log on. I want to share the magic link externally without exposing the actual key as the key changes from time to time and I was hoping to use haproxy as a reverse proxy. I don't want the link to be open to the entire internet and would like to use basic auth as well. The problem I am facing is that the backend overwrites the Authorization header (it's required for the magic link to work) and I get stuck in a loop and need to log on every time

My workaround:

- On first request I request the basic auth (works)
- Then I write it to a cookie (this part works)
- On each subsequent request, if the cookie exists, I read the cookie and set the Authorization header to the cookie value (this part does *not* work)
- Then I run http_auth which in my mind should now work since I have overwritten the header

But it does not work. Any suggestions?

```
userlist auth-list
  user myuser insecure-password mypass

frontend myfrontend
   bind *:80
   mode http
   acl is-path path -i -m beg /publiclink
   acl has_cookie req.hdr(X-MyAuth) -m found
   http-request set-header Authorization %[req.hdr(X-MyAuth)] if has_cookie
   http-request auth unless { http_auth(auth-list) }
   http-request set-var(txn.myhostheader) req.hdr(Authorization) if { http_auth(auth-list) !has_cookie }
   default_backend node

backend node
    mode http
    server dcnode1 192.168.0.1:8000 check
    http-response set-header set-cookie "X-MyAuth=%[var(txn.myhostheader)]; Path=/" if  { var(txn.myhostheader) -m found }
    http-request replace-path /publiclink1(.*) /magiclink\1
    http-request set-header Authorization "Key magiclink"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My answer is related to this point :*

- *On each subsequent request, if the cookie exists, I read the cookie and set the Authorization header to the cookie value (this part does not work)*

In your **backend**, you set the `Set-Cookie: X-MyAuth=...` header :

```
backend node
    http-response set-header set-cookie "X-MyAuth=%[var(txn.myhostheader)]; Path=/" if  { var(txn.myhostheader) -m found }
```

So the **next request** contains a `Cookie` header like this one : `Cookie: .* X-MyAuth=.*`.

But in your **frontend**, you use the `X-MyAuth` header (which probably does not exist) :

```
frontend myfrontend
   acl has_cookie req.hdr(X-MyAuth) -m found
   http-request set-header Authorization %[req.hdr(X-MyAuth)] if has_cookie
```

You may use the `X-MyAuth` **cookie value** like this :

```
frontend myfrontend
   acl has_cookie cook(X-MyAuth) -m found
   http-request set-header Authorization %[cook(X-MyAuth)] if has_cookie
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it!